# Usage of Plus-minus sign

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, standard-error

I have a question concerning statistical conventions. I want to report the classification rate of a 3-fold cross validated machine learning experiment. Of course I report the mean and some measure of the diversity in the different folds. I want to use a shorthand notation like $95.5\% \pm 0.9\%$.

My question is: What is most commonly used as "measure of the diversity"? On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus-minus_sign) we find that standard deviation or standard error is used. On the same page under [In statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus-minus_sign#In_statistics) we find that usually it is corresponding to either 1 or 2 standard deviation.

So is there a best practice what to report? Standard deviation, standard error or even variance? And 1 or 2 times?

Comment: There's differences of conventions in different application areas, and many areas don't even have a convention.

Answer (score 3):

All the three statistics are connected. If you take a square root of variance you get standard deviation: $\sigma = \sqrt \sigma^2$, if you divide standard deviation by square root of number of observations you get standard error: $\text{SE} = \sigma / \sqrt n$. To read more on the differences and similarities between those measures check [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32318/difference-between-standard-error-and-standard-deviation). You often see statistical results described as $X \pm \text{some number} \times \sigma$, those are [confidence intervals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124113/explain-confidence-intervals-in-simple-terms) and in most cases the "1 or 2" number is [chosen](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132536/how-to-choose-a-confidence-level/132538) so that you get 95% confidence intervals. The magic number 1.96 corresponds to 95% confidence interval for a variable with [Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am aware that the three statistics are connected. I would like to know which of them is most commonly used for a report, especially in the case of reporting about the classification rate of a machine learning experiment.

Comment: @FrankZalkow it depends on what information you want to focus on. Check the links I posted to learn more on the differences, that would give you better ideas on when to use which of these.